# Ionic Sticky List (using ion-affix)

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am using plugin **ion-affix** to create a sticky list style for my app. It works fine on iOS device, but it's not working on Android.

Does anyone have any idea or solution for getting it to work on Android?

*Thanks*